# What does "in what" mean in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Shortly afterward, with her cancer in remission, she decided to sue, in what became the first baby-powder lawsuit against Johnson & Johnson to ever make it to trial.

I do not understand the use of "in what" here.

Answer (score 1):

> she decided to sue, [ in [ what became the first baby-powder lawsuit ] ]

"What became the first baby-powder lawsuit" is the object of the preposition "in".

Answer (score 0):

the action of her suing, (in what) is a way to describe the result of an action.

Shortly afterward, with her cancer in remission, she decided to sue, (*the action of her suing*)/ (in what) became the first baby-powder lawsuit against Johnson & Johnson to ever make it to trial.

Answer (score 0):

"in what became" introduces an additional interesting fact about her lawsuit. It starts a new subordinate phrase describing the lawsuit.

It could also have been written "in the" or as a new sentence starting with "It was" or "It became".

Choosing "in what became" rather than "in the" gives a more dramatic flair of something starting small and unnoticeable and then becoming large and significant.

Comment: While I agree with what you say in this answer, I suspect that the OP is having difficulty understanding the syntax, and your answer does not attempt to explain that. Hot Licks' answer does.